# How to evaluate this integral over a region $E$

Tags: integration

$$\int_E \arctan(x+y)x\,dy \text{ where } E = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x+y\le1, x,y\ge0\}$$

I couldn't solve this. I think there is a typing error in this question but I am not sure.  That "$dy$" part made me confused. I found that $E$ region implies $0\le x\le 1$ and $0\le y\le1$. Then I tried setting $f=\arctan(x+y)$, $dy= x\,dx,$ $df=1/((x+y)^2+1) $
and $g=x^2/2$ and did integration by parts but I stuck in some mess calculations.

Comment: I think they meant $dxdy$ instead of $dy$

Comment: A double integral definitely requires two infinitesimals. Your question should be $\int_E \arctan\left(x+y\right)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$

Comment: okay, thanks @ZiadFakhoury

Comment: Why was this question down-voted?

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury : I would typeset it as $\,dx\,dy$ rather than $dx dy.$ Or $\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$ rather than $\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y.$ In the mean time, you might consider up-voting the question.

Comment: @Guy : $\uparrow$ See above. $\qquad$

Comment: I wonder if it was intended to say $$ \iint\limits_E \arctan(x+y)\,dx\,dy $$ so that the function being integrated is $(x,y)\mapsto\arctan(x+y)$ rather than $(x,y)\mapsto\arctan(x+y)\cdot x. \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \iint\limits_E \arctan(x+y)\,d(x,y) = \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{1-y} \arctan(x+y)\, dx \right) dy \\[10pt]
= {} & \int\left( \int s\,dt \right) dy = \int \left( ts - \int t\,ds \right) dy \qquad \left( \begin{array}{l} \text{where } t=x+y,\\ s=\arctan(x+y) \end{array} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int \left( \left[ t\arctan t \vphantom{\frac11} \right]_y^1 - \int_y^1 t \frac{dt}{1+t^2} \right) dy \\[10pt]
= {} &\int_0^1 \left( \frac \pi 4 - y\arctan y - \left[ \frac 1 2 \log(1+t^2) \right]_y^1 \right) \,dy \\[10pt]
 = {} & \int_0^1 \left( \frac \pi 4 - y \arctan y - \left( \frac 1 2 \log 2 - \frac 1 2 \log(1+y^2) \right) \right) dy
\end{align}
Whether one can go further with that I haven't thought about yet, but at this point I wonder whether a different approach will work better:
\begin{align}
u & = x+y \\
v & = y/(x+y) \\[10pt]
x & = u(1-v) \\
y & = uv \\[10pt]
dx\,dy & = \left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right| \, du\,dv = u \, du \, dv
\end{align}
\begin{align}
& \iint\limits_E \arctan(x+y)\,d(x,y) = \iint u \arctan u \,d(u,v) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 u\arctan u \,du  \right)\,dv = \int_0^1 u \arctan u\,du = \cdots 
\end{align}
At this point use integration by parts similarly to the way it was done above.
The reason why $\displaystyle \int_0^1\cdots\,dv$ vanishes is that the expression within that integral does not change as $v$ goes from $0$ to $1,$ so it's like $\displaystyle\int_0^1 5\,dv = 5.$